# How to run this Search function in background Thread

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, list, swiftui

i'm try to run this search in a background thread, using swiftUI, but I don't know where and how to put the code `DispatchQueue.global().async {}`

I have tried to put in the main view where I render the list that display the result, but give me error. I try to put it inside the function that run the searh, but as well give me error.

here my view with the searchbar and the function

```
 var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //            fakebar
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)

            List{

                ForEach(dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector)) { item in
                    Text(item.aptICAO)
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

here my function of search

```
  func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: AirportVector) -> [AirportModel]  {
        // if I use like this Xcode give me warning Cannot convert return expression of type '()' // to return type '[AirportModel]'

        DispatchQueue.global().async {  
               arrayTosearh.filter {
            //        valoreSearhed.isEmpty ? true :
                            $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed)
                        }
        }



    }
```

if I remove the dispatch Queue the search work perfect but it block my view for few second.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use a background thread or DispatchQueue to perform a search function, you cannot expect the function to return [AirportModel] since the function will continue to run and `return` before it even finishes the search.

That is why XCode tells you that it cannot return (), it cannot detect a return type in a linear fashion.

What I would recommend is to use closures to get the details you need. Here is a snippet of what you can do:

```
func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: AirportVector, completionBlock: (airports: [AirportModel]) -> Void)  {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {  
        let results  = arrayTosearh.filter { $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed) }
        completionBlock(results)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        //            fakebar
        SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
        List {
            dm.filter(valoreSearhed: searchTerm, arrayTosearh: dm.airportVector) { airports in 
                ForEach(airports) { airport in
                    Text(airport.aptICAO)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try ur function, but getting many warning like, Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' or Expected '{' in body of function declaration, Function types cannot have argument labels; use '_' before 'airports'

Comment: I add in this post the code I wrote, but Xcode keep give me warning [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596993/solve-this-competition-block] `Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[AirportModel]'`

Comment: You need to remove `-> [AirportModel] as it no longer returns it in a linear manner. I have edited the function to reflect what it supposed to be the correct function

Comment: Still, give error...Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '_'