# Solve this completion Block

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, closures, swiftui

i'm try to solve this completion block, but I keep having many warning.

Xcode give me warning

> Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[AirportModel]'

Sorry I'm a beginner... little lost on this closure...

I have to return this vector of `AirportModel` in order to be display in a list in swiftUI, I want use `DispatchQueue` in order to avoid to block the view while searching:

```
func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: AirportVector, completionBlock: (_ airports: [AirportModel]) -> Void) -> [AirportModel]  {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let results  = arrayTosearh.filter { $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed) }
        completionBlock(results)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn’t the closure.

The problem that you’ve defined this `filter` method to return an `[AirportModel]`, but it doesn’t. Get rid of that `-> [AirportModel]` at the end of the function declaration. You’re not returning anything from this function. You’re using the completion handler to pass the results back.

---

By the way, don’t forget to mark your closure as `@escaping`, too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by intention it should return temporary empty array, so I'd recommend the following

```
func filter (valoreSearhed: String, arrayTosearh: AirportVector, completionBlock: @escaping (_ airports: [AirportModel]) -> Void) -> [AirportModel]  {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let results  = arrayTosearh.filter { $0.aptICAO.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(valoreSearhed) }
        completionBlock(results)
    }
    return []
}
```